# How to change values in excel acording to different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excelsheet which contains two sheets named respectively '`Sertifika`' and '`Egitim Katılım`'. in `Sertifika` i need a button which upgrades value of cells B6, M2 and M3 to next cells from `Egitim Katılım`.

Example:

```
B6 ='Eğitim katılım'!C149
```

and i want to change value of B6 to,

```
='Eğitim katılım'!C150
```

how can it be possible?

Comment: is it just the 3cells that you want to change?

Comment: yes just these three cells

Comment: If its just 3 cells, why do need a macro to do it? why not manually? just curious

Comment: i have to iterate over the cells i have at least 500 records on the sheet named 'Egitim Katılım'

Comment: Got it. So even if its just 3 cells, you may have to use the button 500 times to iterate. Am i right?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: And you did not mention anything about the formulas in other 2 cells

Comment: `B6 ='Eğitim katılım'!C196`, 
`M2 ='Eğitim katılım'!E196`, 
`M3='Eğitim katılım'!D196`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know how to use a button, include the below code inside the command button,

```
Sub mac()
Dim str As String, a As String
str = Range("B6").Formula
a = Right(str, (Len(str) - InStr(str, "C")))
a = a + 1
Range("B6").Formula = "='E?itim kat?l?m'!C" & a
End Sub
```

The code extracts the formula in cell `B6`, unstrings the row number from the formula, adds +1 to it and updated the formula. I would like you to manipulate this for the other 2 cells.